# Integration Under the integral sign on indefinite integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

Is it possible to perform the differentiation under the integral sign for an indefinite integral (anti-derivative)?
that is,

if $f(s) = \int F(s,t) dt $

then, is

$f'(s) = \int (d/ds(F(s,t)))dt$

where all the integrations are indefinite (without any limits)?

Answer (score 1):

For nicely behaved functions you can do this
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\int F(s,t)dt = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial s} F(s,t) dt
$$
If $s,t$ are completely independent. I know I used this trick when trying to combine coupled pdes in to a governing pde.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense, because $\int F(s,t) dt $ is not a function of $s$ as it has infinitely many values for each $s$.